# Is there any OTP app available?

Tags: apps, 2fa

I need an app that can generate One Time Passwords so that I can log in to my Microsoft account and my Google account without having to wait for a text. Google wants me to download their iOS app "Google Authenticator" but I'm a Windows Phone user so I can't. Is there any app available that can generate One Time Passwords?

Comment: Mikael, I don't mean to discourage you from contributing to this site or anything, but it seems to me that some of your recent questions are, for lack of a better word, trivial, in the sense that they add little value to the site because the answer is easily found by searching on Bing/Google or in the WP Store. Good questions [should be based on actual problems that you face](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [should demonstrate research effort](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Please try to keep that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @Indrek, let me try again and see if my next questions got any more quality.

Comment: Soon WP will pass 5 questions per day :) http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone

Comment: That's nice, but getting X questions per day shouldn't be a goal unto itself, because getting an "okay" or higher in every category on Area51 doesn't guarantee the site will graduate from beta. It's the quality of the content that matters, as well as the amount of incoming traffic, and "seeding" the site with trivial questions to artificially push the numbers higher will do little to help with that. You could have 100 questions per day and the site could still wither and die, because the answers are easily found elsewhere as well, and the actual good questions are being drowned out.

Comment: For more information, read [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate) and [Does this site have a chance of succeeding?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding) on the Stack Overflow blog. Personally, I'm more worried about the fact that our visits/day figure seems to be dropping over time.

Comment: @Indrek, Mikael These comments aren't the place to have this discussion - comments should be used to refine the question; instead, you should use meta. I've started a [discussion on the etiquette on self answering questions on there already](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/256/106)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, there is. It's even developed by Microsoft. Its name is simply "[Authenticator](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=e7994dbc-2336-4950-91ba-ca22d653759b)" and it's available in the Store.